# Decimal DataAnnotations no Valida mas de 999,999

Tags: c#, mvc, model

Tengo un decimal que al ingresar un valor mayor a 999999 este no lo deja como valido en el model state.

[Required]
[Range(0,9, errormesage...)]
public decimal variable {get;set;}

he probado sacando el dataannotations cambiando maxlength del input he probado agregar max y min, y nada.

alguna idea de que pueda ser?

Comment: y cual es la restricción que quieres darle a ese decimal?

Comment: solo necesito que me acepte valores decimales mayores a 20 millones

Comment: "que acepte valores mayores a 20 millones" yo leo eso y entiendo que no debe tener restricciones como por ejemplo rango de valores o cantidad de decimales.., es decir, lo quieres sin restricciones? simplemente sácale el `[Required] [Range(0,9, errormesage...)]`

Comment: lo que pasa es que debo validarlo si o si. el problema esta en que el input tiene una mascara decimal por javascript y esta mascara le coloca los separadores de miles y decimales. luego cuando es mayor a 999,999 este valor llega en 0 al controlador. entonces lo que no quiero es tener que setear la variable quitarle estos separadores y luego hacer el submit

Comment: "debo validarlo"... que es lo que debes validar, cual es la restricción, debe seguir algún formato? a que te refieres con máscara javascript? agarras el número y lo transformas de forma manual? como lo estás mostrando ? es muy probable que puedas darle un formato de despliegue en ves de transformarlo

Comment: Posiblemente, te acepte hasta "999,999" porque lo interpreta como "999 con 999 milésimas", así que cuando llega "1,000,000" dice "un número no puede tener dos separadores de parte entera/fraccional" y protesta. Mira con qué formato te llega y con qué formato interpretas lo que te llega de la web.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que 999,999 solo será igual a 999999 cuando estés en un locale/culture que use la coma como separador decimal. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal

Comment: GRACIAS A TODOS POR SU AYUDA E IDEAS